# You need to use a theme with the design library

Tags: java, android, styles, themes

Sometimes after rebuilding my app I get fatal error

> a  IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme
>   (or descendant) with the design library.

I have view-builder class and dynamically add views into the parent layout, it seems it works perfect if I use Activity context, but for some reasons I want to use Application context, so I have this method

```
LayoutInflater provideLayoutInflater(Context context) {
    context.setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDark);
    return (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

`context.setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDark);` it's hack and it seems it doesn't work as expected, but I'm not sure.

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks for any help

Comment: You should never be using the application context for inflating views for your activity.

Answer (score 0):

If the main activity is extending from AppCompatActivity, then it be must use themes descending from AppCompat.